# how to configure specific package in log4j.properties

Tags: spring, log4j

I need to have log4j configuration for specific classes. Does anyone know how can we do it with log4j.properties.

As against, we can add logger with class/package in log4j.xml

```
<logger name="org.springframework.security">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

I want equivalent configuration in log4j.properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern is `log4j.logger.<class or package name>=<level>[, appender]`

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=INFO, console
```